# How to use Select2 with Backbone Marionette views outside the DOM

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, backbone-views, jquery-select2

I'm trying to integrate the Select2 widget with Backbone Marionette views. My simple setup uses a Marionette.CollectionView to create and handle the select tag and Marionette.ItemViews to render the option tags.

That basically looks like this:

```
SelectCollectionView = Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
  itemView : SelectItemView,
  tagName : "select",

  onRender : function() {
    this.$el.select2();
  },

  onClose : function() {
    this.$el.select2("destroy");
  }
}

SelectItemView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  tagName : "option",

  render : function() {
    // create the needed option tags
  }
}
```

As you can see, I have to call the Select2 initialize and destroy methods upon render and close to have the needed additional tags added to the DOM.

This setup works very well, as long as the view handling the select tag (SelectCollectionView) has already been added to the DOM. If that is not the case, Select2's additional tags get lost, as they are not part of SelectCollectionView's $el and thus not added to the DOM.

I wonder how to elegantly solve this? One could add an extra div container and render everything inside it, but that would produce extra code for the script and the DOM. It also makes my view less versatile. I just hope for a better solution I didn't think of.

Comment: i dont understand, you use onRender, thus the select and all option elements are rendered already and added to the dom. Why should your solution then not work?

Comment: @Luke Calling render() on a Backbone just renders the view to its current el. That el might just exist in memory and need not already be attached to the DOM. This creates problems with many widgets that rely on working inside the DOM – one reason I opted for Select2 instead of Chosen.

Comment: Have you tried using `onShow` instead of `onRender` ?

Answer (score 1):

As you suspect, you are going to need a containing div to surround your template.  Fortunately, this is really simple.  Instead of what you currently have:

```
SelectCollectionView = Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
  tagName : "select"
```

Get rid of `tagName`, and in your template (I'm assuming you use Handlebars or Underscore or something like that), define your HTML:

#### template.html

```
<select class="whatever-you-want"></select>
```

Then in your view:

#### SelectCollectionView.js

```
SelectCollectionView = Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
  template: _.template(templateHtml)
```

Marionette will automatically wrap a div around your `<select>`, and then all of the extra markup that select2 adds will be safely contained within the view's `$el`.

Answer (score 0):

It took me some time to figure it out, but I used to solve it this way:

```
    var Select2View = Mn.View.extend({
      template: _.template('<select class="form-control"><option></option></select>'),

      onRender:function() {
        this.$el.find('select').select2();
      }
    });
```

The important part here is

```
this.$el.find('select').select2();
```

which select the **select** tag, inside the element. But I don't use collection view in my example. If you need to fetch data you can use:

```
this.$el.find('select').select2({data: ['1','2','3','4']});
```

Also select2 provide very good API for manipulating select items during runtime.